# Get API Return JSON Payload in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, httprequest

I created a Web API and it needs to read the response in header with json content, therefore I use code below:

```
HttpRequestMessage re = Request;
var payLoadJson = re.Content;
string jsonContent = payLoadJson.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var test = JObject.Parse(jsonContent);
```

And here is the response of `var test`

```
{{
  "pushToken": "AAABBBCCC"
}}
```

Can any body tell me how to get the value of `pushToken`?

`JObject.Parse(jsonContent)['pushToken']` always get null because of double braces.

Comment: You can remove your first and last char from the json string to make it a valid JSON

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: How to let it to be valid? Remove the braces will error in reading JObject when the string create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your string in valid Json format:**

```
{
    "pushToken": "AAABBBCCC"
}
```

**Getting the payload**

```
var pushToken = JObject.Parse(json)["pushToken"];
```

*(Also note that pushtoken is between double quotes not single quotes as per your example, you should get an error with singles once)*

or

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var pushToken = obj.pushToken;
```

**As a side note:**

In case you receive that bad invalid Json like you described ... *I would actually have no idea how that's even possible*. Then remove the two braces **before** parsing or deserializing.

```
json = json.Trim();
json = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail ans, it is work now! The invalid Json is come from Apple wallet return HTTP content, and I am still finding what Apple return data exactly. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @YukwongTsang your welcome. But any API should return you valid Json after all.